# (Java) Search indexes of values of an array in another array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, loops, linear-search

I have written the following code that takes two arrays and searches the index of the first occurrence of each value from the first array in the second one. For example if `first = {15, 10, 18, 17, 15}` and `second = {10, 15, 10, 17}` then the output would be an array with an equal length to `first` which contains the indices `output = {1, 0, -1, 3, 1}`, as e.g. 15 occurs in index 1 of the `second` array, 10 occurs at the 0th index, etc. The index will be -1 if the value in `first` doesn't occur in `second`. The code I've written to loop through the arrays is as follows:

```
public static int[] searchIndexes(int[] first, int[] second) {

    int[] indices = new int[first.length];
    int index = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < first.length; i ++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < second.length; j ++) {
            if (first[i] == second[j])
                index = j;
        }
        indices[i] = index;
    }
    return indices;
}
```

However, for the given example the output is instead `{1, 2, 2, 3, 1}`. I think I do understand the issue; since 10 occurs twice in `second` then the index of the **second** occurrence is recorded, but I don't know how to get around this. Putting a `break;` statement after the `if` clause doesn't seem to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This would be straightforward by using the `ArrayUtils.indexOf()` utility method. Moving through the second array, call `ArrayUtils.indexOf()` for each of its elements in reference to the first array, storing the results in the indices array. This will also mean that there would be a single loop, not a nested loop.

The `ArrayUtils` class is a part of the `org.apache.commons.lang3` library.

A different option, not requiring an external library, would be to convert your arrays to `List`s and then take advantage of the `List.indexOf()` method.

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Two issues in your code:

- Once `index` is set to any value at all, it can never again become `-1`
- Once you find the first occurrence in the second array, you keep going - need a `break`.

Updated code:

```
  public static int[] searchIndexes(int[] first, int[] second) {
    int[] indices = new int[first.length];
    int index;

    for (int i = 0; i < first.length; i ++) {
      // reset index on each iteration
      index = -1;
      for (int j = 0; j < second.length; j ++) {
        if (first[i] == second[j]) {
          // once the first match is found, break out of the inner loop
          index = j;
          break;
        }
      }
      indices[i] = index;
    }
    return indices;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    public static int[] searchIndexes(int[] first, int[] second) {

        int[] indices = new int[first.length];
        //fill all values with -1
        Arrays.fill(indices,0,first.length - 1, -1);

        for (int i = 0; i < first.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < second.length; j++) {
                // when you met with same value fill your indices array with second array's value's index and break the loop
                if (first[i] == second[j]) {
                    indices[i] = j;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return indices;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `break` after found the element and reset the index

```
public static int[] searchIndexes(int[] first, int[] second) {
        int[] indices = new int[first.length];
        int index = -1;

        for (int i = 0; i < first.length; i++) {
            index = -1;
            for (int j = 0; j < second.length; j++) {
                if (first[i] == second[j]) {
                    index = j;
                    break;
                }
            }
            indices[i] = index;
        }
        return indices;
    }
```

, main

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int[] indices = searchIndexes(new int[] { 15, 10, 18, 17, 15 }, new int[] { 10, 15, 10, 17 });
        for (int i = 0; i < indices.length; i++)
            System.out.print(indices[i] + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }
```

, output

```
1 0 -1 3 1
```